# Send data from python script to socket.io server

Tags: python, node.js, socket.io

I have the following problem:

I hava a python script and a socket.io server running on my machine. 
Now, I want to pass Data fom the python script to the Server and the client.
At the moment, I am using the following:

Server:

```js
  fs.watchFile('position.txt', function (curr, prev) {
    //console.log('the current mtime is: ' + curr.mtime);
    //console.log('the previous mtime was: ' + prev.mtime);
    io.emit('positionswechsel', curr.mtime); //need the content of the file here
  });
```

Python:

```
def my_callback2(channel):
    fout=open("../sio/position.txt","w")
    fout.write("P1")
    fout.close()
print "falling edge detected on 18"
```

In this solution, I see a very high latency between the event (writing file) and the reaction of my server.

Now, I thought there should be a way to directly pass information from the python script to the server/client (I want to see the change on the webpage).

Yan anybody please help me?

Yannic

Answer (score 0):

There is already a [socket.io 1.0 client for Python](https://github.com/invisibleroads/socketIO-client).

If that doesn't work for you for whatever reason, you could always just establish a plain TCP connection (or use a UNIX socket) between the two processes and transfer newline-delimited JSON from Python to node, which then gets emitted to connection socket.io clients in some form or another.

Comment: Hi, thank you.
Unfortunately, I fail installing the client. Can anybody help?